# How to exclude the files with all the 4-digit numbers without the first five numbers by wild card in tree command

Tags: wildcards, tree

I want to exclude list the following number

```
0005
0006
...
9998
9999
```

I try the following code, but failed

And I use

```
 tree -I '*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][5-9]'
```

But It creates line with
0014 0024...

I want the tree list just include file like

```
*.0000
*.0001
*.0002
*.0003
*.0004
```

But the results shows:

```
*.0000
*.0001
*.0002
*.0003
*.0004
*.0010
*.0011
*.0012
*.0013
*.0014
.....
```

Comment: Please describe in detail what the current output is and what the expected output is.

Comment: @munircontractor yes,

Answer (score 1):

You can you simply substitute the `-I` flag for `-P`, and match directly what you want, like so:

```
tree -P '*.000[0-4]'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to learn how can I use exclude by wildcard

Comment: @yuxuan Why? In this case, picking what you want to _include_ is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude, try `tree -I "*.[1-9][1-9][1-9][5-9]"`.

Anything that can't match will either have a forbidden 0 in at least one of the first 3 slots or will be >4 in the last.

Comment: Note that what I did is simply the complement of @Kira's answer, with the flag switched from `-P` to `-I`.

Comment: It doesn't exclude like `0010,0011,0012,0013,0014, 0015,0016.....`